# What is the difference between these two type annotation and why they are different?

Tags: types, racket, typed-racket

I was trying to add types for this function from the book, Little Schemer.

```
(define rember-fc
  (λ(test?)
    (λ (a l)
      (cond [(null? l) '()]
            [(test? a (car l)) (cdr l)]
            [else
             (cons (car l)
                   ((rember-fc test?) a (cdr l)))]))))
```

**This type cause a error.**

```
(: rember-fc  (∀ (a) (-> (-> Any Any Boolean)  (-> a (Listof a) (Listof a)))))
```

**This type  works.**

```
(: rember-fc  (-> (-> Any Any Boolean)  (∀ (a) (-> a (Listof a) (Listof a)))))
```

I was wondering why these two type cause different results and what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function can work under the first version of the type signature

```
(: rember-fc  (∀ (a) (-> (-> Any Any Boolean)  (-> a (Listof a) (Listof a)))))
```

if you add an annotation where you use the function in the recursive call, replacing

```
((rember-fc test?) a (cdr l))
```

with

```
(((inst rember-fc a) test?) a (cdr l))
```

where the `inst` type annotation allows it to typecheck.

This use of the function has two applications, an inner application and an outer application. The inner application is typechecked first, and the outer application is only typechecked once it has a concrete type for the inner application.

Typed Racket's type inference algorithm is smart enough to figure out what the forall-variable is in `((rember-fc test?) a (cdr l))` when `(rember-fc test?)` has the forall-type and `a` and `(cdr l)` provide the information. The inner application does not require type inference if the forall is in the middle, and the outer application type inference succeeds because the outer application arguments provide the information.

However, the type inference is not smart enough to figure that out when `rember-fc` has the forall-type, and `test?` doesn't provide the information in the inner application. The `a` and `(cdr l)` are only applied later in the outer application. When the type inference can't figure it out, it guesses `Any` in the inner application, and it only finds out that guess was wrong later in the outer application.

So the two working versions are:

```
(: rember-fc  (∀ (a) (-> (-> Any Any Boolean)  (-> a (Listof a) (Listof a)))))
(define rember-fc
  (λ (test?)
    (λ (a l)
      (cond [(null? l) '()]
            [(test? a (car l)) (cdr l)]
            [else
             (cons (car l)
                   (((inst rember-fc a) test?) a (cdr l)))]))))
```

And:

```
(: rember-fc  (-> (-> Any Any Boolean)  (∀ (a) (-> a (Listof a) (Listof a)))))
(define rember-fc
  (λ (test?)
    (λ (a l)
      (cond [(null? l) '()]
            [(test? a (car l)) (cdr l)]
            [else
             (cons (car l)
                   ((rember-fc test?) a (cdr l)))]))))
```